# HTTP Request with NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, http-headers

Im trying to communicate with server from iOS device using NSMutableURLRequest but server close connections with status code 998

i saw in sent packet that contain some strange headers like "sign" and  "requestIndex" someone know what the headers their are ?

```
POST /sessions.json HTTP/1.1
Host: 54.201.34.85
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
sig: B72D4AF524DFAAE5AC78C5456431B2DF
clientv: 1.8.1
openudid: CE1E126D-164C-49FF-95AC-A7D0D80737A3
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Locale: en
Authorization: Basic TzlhSDN6d3FPY3RObjN4SFd6SjlXUSUzRCUzRDpjJTJCclQzUklpJTJCbiUyQm1aamdEZmFKcnJRJTNEJTNE
User-Agent: PE client
os_version: iPhone OS 7.0.4
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Appid: com.tap4fun.galaxyempire
idfa: DABB5364-80AF-4E90-9600-31835745211B
shiqu: Asia
requestIndex: OJpPOuTNxgU1PrxhqrdViA%3D%3D
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
mac_address: 02:00:00:00:00:00
Content-Length: 81
Cookie: 

username=O9aH3zwqOctNn3xHWzJ9WQ%3D%3D&password=a%2BrRWRIi%2Bn%2BmZjgDfaJrrQ%3D%3D
```

Comment: Those are not [standard HTTP header fields](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). They probably unique to your particular web service. Nor is `998` a standard [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). You probably should inquire with the vendor (or look at the code) to figure out why you're getting that code (or understand what the purpose of those custom headers is). You might want to update your question with particulars about the web service you're interacting with and any third-party frameworks you might be using.

Comment: Thank you Rob for Helpful comment i figured out that its a sign and client should use special certificate to sign request and send it to server!